# RecyclerView with reverseLayout "jumps" upon notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I set my recyclerView's layoutManager like this:

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, HORIZONTAL, true)
```

The last parameter sets the `reverseLayout` to `true` which means it will be loaded from right to left. I need this because I implement a sort of calendar where the last date is current date but you can scroll into the past infinitely.

The problem is that when in my adapter I call `notifyItemChanged` or `notifyDataSetChanged` the list scrolls a few pixels to the right. This doesn't happen with `reverseLayout=false`.

**It also only happens while the size of the RecyclerView is `MATCH_PARENT`, when I set it manually to whatever dp, the problem is gone.**

Any ideas what happens and how to cope with it?

Comment: For now I just set the size of the recyclerView manually and it works as a workaround, but it would be great to fix it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is too late, but anyway, I'm leaving this here. 
Using constraint layout with match constraints on recyclerview (0dp with horizontal constraints) solved the problem for me.

Comment: 0dp doesn't work for me. MATCH_PARENT actually fixes it but I want it between two WRAP_CONTENT views so can't use that.

Answer (score 0):

Setting RecyclerView dimensions programmatically worked for me.

In kotlin -

```
constraintLayout.doOnLayout {
    recyclerview.layoutParams.height = bottomLayout.top - appBarLayout.bottom
}
```

xml -

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomLayout" />
```

Where I want recyclerView between bottomLayout and appBarLayout and constraintLayout is root layout.